# UWP MapControl, how to handle map element select and unselect events?

Tags: c#, xaml, maps, win-universal-app, windows-10

In my UWP app I want user to allow select map element (to see detailed info) and unselect the map element by clicking empty are of the map.

In MapControl there are two events which I try to use:

**MapElementClick(MapControl sender, MapElementClickEventArgs args)**

- This event is fired when user clicks map element, I can handle map element selection here.

**MapTapped(MapControl sender, MapInputEventArgs args)**

- This event is fired when user tap's map. I could handle map element unselection here but the problem is that this event is also fired when map element is tapped.

How I should handle this map element unselection? I think there is no way how I can cancel click/tap event bubble from MapElementClick() to prevent MapTapped() firing?

Comment: Why  not use a bool value on Tapped set `bool mapselected=!mapselected` and you can also specify `OnLostFocus` to set the mapselected valsue to false. This way you can handle both if user taps on mapelement to select and unselect and if user taps outside to unselect.

Comment: I do not know did I get your idea correctly. My problem is that when I click map element I get both events MapElementClick and MapTapped. So with just single bool variable my map element gets unselected immediately after MapElementClick when I get MapTapped event?

Answer (score 1):

This is my first answer here and I'm also kind of a C# newbie so be gentle pls :D

I had the same problem, and this is the workaround i did: I created two grids over my MapControl, one with margin, this is where you can show the detailed information, and an outer grid, which will detect the tap outside the information grid:

```c#
<Grid>
    <maps:MapControl
       x:Name="MapControl"
       MapElementClick="MapControl_MapElementClick"
       MapServiceToken="YourMapToken">
    <Grid Name="OverlayGrid"
          Background="Transparent"
          Visibility="Collapsed"
          Tapped="OverlayGrid_Tapped"/>
    <Grid Name="InfoGrid"
          Margin="50,50,50,50"
          BorderBrush="Firebrick"
          BorderThickness="2"
          Background="White"
          Visibility="Collapsed"/>
</Grid>
```

In the codebehind:

```
        private void MapControl_MapElementClick(MapControl sender, MapElementClickEventArgs args)
        {
            InfoGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            OverlayGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }
        private void OverlayGrid_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            InfoGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            OverlayGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
```

This way whatever MapElement you click on will show you the grid where you can show your detailed information for the specific Mapelement, and if you click outside, both will be hidden. Of course you can use any other layout control for showing the information you want.